# Passing variable names as arguments in R yields unexpected result

Tags: r

Could anyone please explain to me why the following function call returns 'NULL' instead of 1?

```
> df <- data.frame(1,2,3)
> df
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  2  3
> f <- function(vdf, vx) { return (vdf$vx); }
> f(df, "X1")
NULL
>
```

Comment: You could try `f <- function(vdf, vx) {vdf[,vx]}; f(df, "X1")` instead, but it seems that I don't know why your code isn't working

Comment: It happens for the same reason that `col="X1";df$col` returns NULL. R position matches `"X1"` to the argument `vx` and `$` does not evaluate its argument so the function is searching for `df$vx` regardless of the value you assign to the argument `vx`.

Comment: [**Here's a bit more info**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381) and another example.

Comment: Thanks folks. Should I delete it ?